# How do I convert Uppercase letters to their correspondent Unicode value?

Tags: python

I am a noob programmer trying to create a simple python program that converts letters to their correspondent Unicode values. The program works for lowercase letters, but does not do anything for uppercase letters.

Here is the code

```
#ask user to enter a string
message = input("Enter your message: ")

#convert string to unicode
#print resultant number
print("Your scrambled message is: ", end='')

for char in message:
    if (96 >= ord(char) <= 122):
        print(char, end='')
    elif (65 >= ord(char) <= 90):
        print(char, end='')
    else:
       print(ord(char), end='')

print()

#allow user to unscramble
while True:
    response = input("Would you like to unscramble the message? (y/n): ")

#print original message
    if response == 'y':
        print("Unscrambled")
        print(message)
        break
    elif response == 'n':
        print("Ok! Keep your secrets")
        break
    else:
        print("Unknown error!")
```

Answer (score 2):

You had the signs wrong in the if conditions, and I think you want to print `ord(char)` if the conditions are met.

So:

```
for char in message:
    #print(char, ord(char),  end='')
    if (65 <= ord(char) <= 90):
        print(ord(char), end='')
    elif (96 <= ord(char) <= 122):
        print(ord(char), end='')
    else:
        print(char, end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
message = input("Enter your message: ")

#convert string to unicode
#print resultant number
print("Your scrambled message is: ", end='')

for char in message:
    if (96 <= ord(char) <= 122):
        print(char, end='')
    elif (65 <= ord(char) <= 90):
        print(char, end='')
    else:
       print(ord(char), end='')

print()
```

You've confused the sign in condition

Comment: If this code helped, mark it as the "correct answer"

Answer (score 1):

You have done mistake in using your if statement and printing

```
for char in message:
   if (96 >= ord(char)) and (ord(char) <= 122):
      print(ord(char), end='')
   elif (65 >= ord(char)) and (ord(char) <= 90):
      print(ord(char), end='')
   else:
      print(ord(char), end='')
```

In future you can also use `range(start,end)` instead of using such complex `if` statement,

```
for char in message:
   if ord(char) in range(96,123):
      print(ord(char), end='')
   elif ord(char) in range(65,91) <= 90):
      print(ord(char), end='')
   else:
      print(ord(char), end='')
```

Instead of calling `ord()` many times you can use a variable instead,

```
for char in message:
   o=ord(char)
   if o in range(96,123):
      print(o, end='')
   elif o in range(65,91) <= 90):
      print(o, end='')
   else:
      print(o, end='')
```

Above program will solve your problem but efficient way to do your task would be simple as this as there is not much use of if condition in your program.

```
for char in message:
    print(ord(char), end='')
```